# Do both alternatives match when using | in Perl regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I am confused about the regular expression below. Please help me to understand it.

```
my $test = "fred andor berry";
if ($test =~ /fred (and|or) berry/) {
    print "Matched!\n";
} else {
      print "Did not match!\n";
}
```

I thought it would match, but I get "Did not match!". If I add `+` in it, like this,

```
my $test = "fred andor berry";
if ($test =~ /fred (and|or)+ berry/) {
   print "Matched!\n";
} else {
   print "Did not match!\n";
}
```

Then it matches. I thought I can use `and|or` to match an expression with "and", "or" and "andor". No?

Comment: and+ means after "and" you have some characters,  or+ means after "or" you have some characters.

Comment: Yes,but I think these characters is same as the one before +

Comment: No, guru, the `+` means "one or more of the preceding symbol". In the OP's regex, the preceding symbol is `(and|or)` which only matches "and" or "or". It does not match any other sequence of characters. In `and+`, the preceding symbol is `d`, so the `+` would allow for additional `d`s, not a generic "some characters".

Comment: Please make your question title more specific.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman, exactly, for (and)+,the preceding is and, so it can match andandand....

Comment: @reinierpost, Ok, I will pay attention on it in the future:)

Comment: @abner: You can improve this one, too, e.g. `Do both alternatives match when using | in Perl regular expressions?`

Comment: @reinierpost, yes, it will be better, and now, can I change the topic?

Comment: @reinierpost, I have already modified the tile , sorry for causing troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(and|or)` will match `and` or `or`, but not `andor`. When you add the `+`, it will accept two (actually one or more) consecutive matches of the same pattern, which allows it to match `andor`. (First it matches `and`, then `or`.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have the same idea with you about "The expression (and|or) will match and or or, but not andor",but with same tests, I found /(and|or)/ can match "andor", so strange~

Comment: @abner: What is "the below one"?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the comments:)

Comment: There was probably something else about your other tests that caused it to happen then. :)

Comment: Maybe, do you have an environment to run the below script, help me to check whether it's OK in your environment, my $test = "andor";

if($test =~ /and|or/){
  print "Matched!\n";
}else{
  print "Donot Matched!\n";
}

Comment: That expression will match either `and` or `or` anywhere in the string. So, it matches `andor` because it can find `and` somewhere in the string, and likewise it can find `or` in the string. It is not matching the entire sequence `andor`, just a part of it.

Comment: By the way, we would say "Not matched" ... "Donot matched" doesn't really make sense :)

Comment: thanks for the correction, so when to match andor,the procedure is like: oh, I found and in the expression ,then return true, it donnot needs to continue, right?

Comment: Exactly. By default, a regular expression just matches anywhere in the expression. There are some extra things you can add to change that if you want. I highly recommend you read the documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: @abner, You seem to have a good understanding now. So just one more thing: Compare `"abc" =~ /a(?:b|c)/` with `"abc" =~ /^a(?:b|c)\z/`. The first matches (since it matches `/ab/`), but the second doesn't (since the "`b`" isn't followed by the end of the string).

Answer (score 11):

The part of the regex that is `(and|or)` means match 'and' or 'or' but not both. When you append the plus to that group it can then match one or more times. For example "fred andandand berry" would also be a valid match for `/fred (and|or)+ berry/`

Answer (score 5):

While people tend to read `a|b` as "a or b" the `|` is not an OR operator; it's the *alternation* operator. It specifies a set of *alternatives* for what can match at that point. A more accurate reading would be "either 'a' or 'b' (but not both)".

When you write `(and|or)+` you're adding the `+` quantifier, which means "one or more of the preceding atom." The effect is that instead of matching a single value which could be either "and" or "or", it will match a series of values, each of which could be either "and" or "or". It would match all of the following:

```
and
or
andor
orand
andorand
andandorororandorandand
```

If you really want to match just "and", "or", and "andor" (though I don't know why you'd want to) you would write it like this:

```
(and|or|andor)    # capture
(?:and|or|andor)  # don't capture
```

depending on whether or not you wanted to capture the specific value matched. (Plain `(...)` creates a capturing grouping. `(?:...)` creates a non-capturing grouping.)

Answer (score 3):

When matching an atom, it must come immediately after the previous atom.

There are two kinds of "or".

- Exclusive or
- Inclusive or

- If `|` was an exclusive or, it would match if it finds either "or" or "and" immediately after `fred`.
- If `|` was an inclusive or, it would match if it finds "or", "and" or both immediately after `fred`.

Both `and` and `or` cannot possible be found immediately after `fred`, so `|` is obviously an exclusive or.

Answer (score 1):

(and|or)+ means multiple occurences but atleast one of either. so it would also match andand, andorand, orand, ororororand etc.

(and|or) means either and or or. (nice namepicking)

So it would match on

fred and berry

and on

fred or berry

proper documentation if you want to continue with regex can be found at

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Thank you, with some tests, I found /(and|or)/ can match "andor", so strange~

Comment: just /(and|or)/ will definately match on andor but if you make the regex like you posted before you dont just say match this group (and|or) you also say that there should be fred and a space before the group and a space and berry after the group. Just the regex (and|or) will also match on andorand andandorand and ororoand etc (any combination of and and or in no particular sequence)

Comment: so ,do you think /fred (and|or)/ can match "fred andor"?

Comment: My tests show it can match "fred andor", I think because it can find and in that expression

Comment: yes it matches because it finds "fred and" and is satified. I generally use http://www.regextester.com/ which will highlight the matches for you